# Random Hex Color

Tags: javascript, math, hex

This is the javascript to generate a random hex color:

```
'#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
```

could anyone talk me through it?

I understand how the Math.random works (as well as the to String at the end), but I don't understand the syntax after that. Questions I have:

1. How can Math.random() multiplied by F output a number?
2. What does the <<0 mean?
3. What does the parameter of 16 on toString mean? (does it mean no
   more than 16 letters?)

Would really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,

Raph

Comment: `0xFFFFFF` Thats a hex number. `<< 0` is just an ugly way of `Math.floor` and `16` is the radix, thats what the docs are for

Comment: As Jonas said, `Math.random()` gives you a random number from `[0,1)`, then, its multiplied by the largest HEX number which is `0xFFFFFF`, then it shifts the bits to the left using `<<0` and convert back to hex using `.toString(16)`. But you shouldnt ask those questions here, you question might be closed

Answer (score 1):

#### It looks like you picked this up on codegolf.

> How can Math.random() multiplied by F output a number?

It is not multiplied by F. `0xFFFFFF` is converted to `16777215`, as `0xFFFFFF` is just the hexadecimal way of writing `16777215`.

> What does the <<0 mean?

`<<` is a bitshift operator. `<<0` shifts all bits 0 places to the left (filler: 0). This doesn't make any sense though. In this case it just deletes any decimal places.

> What does the parameter of 16 on toString mean? (does it mean no more than 16 letters?)

The 16 is the parameter for the numeral system. (2 is binary, 8 is octal, 10 is decimal/normal, 16 is hexadecimal, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

## The best way to generate random HEX color:

It contains of tow functions:

1. The fest one picks a random hex number.
2. and the second one creates an array with hex values.

   // Returns one possible value of the HEX numbers

   ```
   function randomHex() {
       var hexNumbers = [
       0,
       1,
       2,
       3,
       4,
       5,
       6,
       7,
       8,
       9,
       'A',
       'B',
       'C',
       'D',
       'E',
       'F'
   ]

       // picking a random item of the array
     return hexNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexNumbers.length)];
   }


   // Genarates a Random Hex color
   function hexGenerator() {
       hexValue = ['#'];
       for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
           hexValue.push(randomHex());
       }

       return hexValue.join('');
   }


   // print out the random HEX color
   document.write(hexGenerator());
   ```

good luck